# The import org.apache.camel cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, spring

Yesterday I was working in my project. Today when I opened eclipse there is an error:

`The import org.apache.camel cannot be resolved` in .java file.

I tried to add **`.jar`** file then I got another error:

`The import org.springframework cannot be resolved`.

Then I tried to add this **`.jar`** and I got another error. What happened overnight?

Note: There is maven integration with my eclipse.

Comment: Try to clean project on eclipse if jars on classpath

Comment: Sorry guys there was unsupported line in pom.xml file that's why maven dependencies unable to download. Now its working after I remove unsupported line from pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify versions for each library defined in pom.xml file.